# Magento 2 : Marketplace Type Error occurred when creating object error in Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento2, marketplace, magento2-enterprise

> I have uploaded the extension in the marketplace, but it's failed in
> the enterprise edition. There is no issue in the community version.

I have tried to resolve the error by clearing `var/generation` folder and running **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** command but it's not working.

[image: Error]

**Review Results:**

```
Test environments Used: 
Magento 2.3.5 Enterprise Edition (PHP 7.3.17)
Magento ver. 2.2.11 Enterprise Edition (PHP 7.2.30)
```

**Report:-**

> [2020-06-23 09:46:37] report.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when
> creating object:
> Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection\Interceptor,
> Argument 5 passed to
> Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection\Interceptor::__construct()
> must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
> or be null, string given, called in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
> on line 121 [] [] [2020-06-23 09:46:37] report.CRITICAL: Type Error
> occurred when creating object:
> Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection\Interceptor
> [] []

> **Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection.php**

```
<?php
    
    namespace Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates;
    
    /**
     * Templates model collection
     */
    class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
    {
        
        /**
         * init constructor
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init(
                \Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\Templates::class,
                \Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates::class
            );
        }
    }
```

> **Myvendor\GiftCard\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="TemplateGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>   
   <virtualType name="TemplateGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">TemplateGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">gift_templates</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="rocktech_giftcard_data_source" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
    <virtualType name="CodeSetGridFilter" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>   
    <virtualType name="CodesetProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Codeset\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">CodeSetGridFilter</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Codeset\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">gift_code_set</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Codeset</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="rocktech_codeset_datasource" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Codeset\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
    <virtualType name="AccountGridFilter" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>   
   <virtualType name="CodesetProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Account\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">AccountGridFilter</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Account\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">gift_code_account</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="account_dataset" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Account\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="form_data" xsi:type="string">EntityItemGridCollection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="EntityItemGridCollection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">gift_templates</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\ResourceModel\Templates</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Design" type="Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\Design" /> 
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Configure" type="Myvendor\GiftCard\Controller\Cart\Configure" />   
     <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="check_customer_for_GiftCard" type="Myvendor\GiftCard\Plugin\AccountManagement" />
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\PaymentMethodManagement" type="Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\PaymentMethodManagement" /> 
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="Myvendor\GiftCard\Block\Giftorder\Totals" />    
    <preference for="Myvendor\GiftCard\Api\GiftCardManagementInterface" type="Myvendor\GiftCard\Model\GiftCardManagement" />
</config>
```

**If Anyone has any ideas, please let me know.**

Comment: Show your di.xml

Comment: updated a question, please check.

Comment: @SohelRana do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am going through the same issue, help !

Comment: @GustavoUlyssea I haven't found the solution yet

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me to fix the issue, it appears that the virtual type collection name has to be different than the class namespace - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/290477