# Error with virtualType collection construct

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, collection, upgrade, virtualtype

I am upgrading from Magento 2.2.4 to 2.3.5. I have this collection using virtualTyp made by someone else. I don't understand what's going on.

Anyone can help ? THanks !!

```
<virtualType name="Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Resource\Items\Collection" 
type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">intelipost_pickup_items</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" 
xsi:type="string">Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Resource\Items</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Error message:

```
[2020-08-24 21:09:44] report.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object:
Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Resource\Items\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to 
Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Resource\Items\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement 
interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, string given, called in 
.../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 [] []
```

This is the collection code:

```
<?php

namespace Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Resource\Items;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Items',
            'Intelipost\Pickup\Model\Resource\Items'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: I had the same issue, this answer fixed it for me - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/290477

Answer (score 0):

Did you run bin/magento di:compile ? If not please run that command once. If the problem still persist then just let me know.

Comment: I surely did :) Unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: Please check your collection class of that model. Seems to have an error with that class. Also you can share that code here.

Comment: Dear @Predipta I have just added the collection code. Could not solve it yet. Help ? Thanks !